# Avoid security risk of Meteor collection update multi:true via Meteor.methods

Tags: javascript, security, collections, meteor

Let's say I'm writing a reactive collection widget that needs to update multiple records in a collection; for example, a grid will update the "checked" state of multiple records as a result of a user action.

The problem is, [Meteor doesn't let you run Collection.update(..., ..., {multi:true})](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/update):

> Untrusted code can only modify a single document at once

Of course, I could do a forEach on the Collection.find() results, but this is inefficient.

Another problem is that a widget, by necessity, will take the collection as a parameter. Creating a `Meteor.method` "update" that takes the collection name as a parameter opens a security risk, in that an evil user could pass in arbitrary collection names.

What is a better way to update multiple records from the client, and [why doesn't Meteor allow this](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3271#issuecomment-66586813), since it would be less risky than forcing the developer to define exploitable methods in this scenario (arbitrary collection)?

Comment: Why not store the rank/order as a floating-point number? That way, you only need to update the rank of a single item when they are reordered.

Comment: @stubailo: that's what [Avital demoed](https://www.meteor.com/blog/2013/09/13/previewing-meteors-new-rendering-engine-reactive-sortable-lists), but the problem is that after <50 updates, you'll run into the limitations of floating point precision. Drop an element between 2 and 3, set its rank to 2.5; drop another -> 2.25; 2.125 etc. until the math will round to either 2 or 3.

Comment: Anyway, the problem is [larger](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3271#issuecomment-66586813) than a particular solution to that example, so I've removed it from the question.